# Sudoku initials board generator Java Script

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, infinite-loop, sudoku

I'm trying to make Sudoku game in JavaScript (with React).
I have an idea that I will generate a complete Sudoku board for initial.
In JSX I created 81 fields (inputs) with class col1, col2, col3... and the same row1, row2, row3... ( **For now ONLY rules with row and column, without this big Square rule** ).

Im trying make initial function when every fields get proper value.
This function look like this for now:

```
        const setAllNumbers = () => {
        for(let i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
            const currentRow = [...document.querySelectorAll(`.row${i}`)];
            const currentCol = [...document.querySelectorAll(`.col${i}`)];
            let counter = 0;


            while (counter < 9) {
                const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1) + 1);
                const isDuplicateRow = currentRow.filter(ele => parseInt(ele.value)  === random);
                const isDuplicateCol = currentCol.filter(ele => parseInt(ele.value)  === random);

                if(isDuplicateRow.length === 0 && isDuplicateCol.length === 0){
                    currentRow[counter].value = random;
                    counter++;
                }else{
                    counter--;
                }
            }

         }
    }
```

**What I think I do:**

1. I created FOR, for 9 loop ( cuz 9 rows )
2. Inside loop, I get all elements with row1,col1.. row2,col2.. etc. One by one.
3. I created WHILE, for 9 loop ( cuz 9 fields in every row )
4. In every loop I get Random number from 1 to 9
5. Check that any of col1 element or row1 elements have this value already.
6. If any of col1 and row1 HAVE NOT this number, I can put number in current element and go to another.
7. If any of col1 or row1 HAVE this number already, I back my COUNTER by 1, and loop start again from this same element until get a good result.

Well, it's not working as I expected... It's get infinite loop probably because my browser freezes when I run this app.

Matt

Comment: `counter < 9` is probably always resolving to `true`

Comment: @evolutionxbox But It shouldnt be always true. As You can see, I ++ when its correct number and -- when It is ucorrect. This way it should be generate full, properly board instead run to infinite loop.

Comment: That’s the next step. To figure out why it counter is never more than 8.